# Python: How to replace a sublist inside a list by a string

Tags: python, arrays, list

So i have a list, with sublists in it and if a certain condition is true i want to replace that whole sublist by a string.

Here is my code:

```
if list[1] not in forbidden:
            lists[list] = "OK"
```

and here is an example of list i have:

```
[[1, 'im good'], [3, 'sup'], [6, 'no problem']]
```

but when i try to run this code i get this error:

```
lists[list] = "OK"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

and what i want to have is this (just an example):

```
[OK, [3, 'sup'], OK]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a list element as an index, you need to get the actual numeric index.

You can use `enumerate()` to get the list indexes and values when iterating over the list.

```
for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    if l[1] not in forbidden:
        lists[i] = 'OK'
```

P.S. Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a standard function name.